# EE Site without cookies

Tags: cookies

I want to completely opt out of cookies on my site. I don't have registration, comments are anonymous, using third party search site. Are there any unobvious nuances and disadvantages?

If I choose the user session type - only the session identifier and do not use {path} and {route} tags in the templates (which insert a string identifier into the address), then there will be no problems with changing addresses and using them?

What should I consider?

Comment: It is difficult to enable completely cookie-less operation for a php based CMS as you cannot easily the session cookies used by php.

Most cookie regulations appear to tolerate use of transient cookies (i.e. those that do not persist between sessions). EE 6.1 introduced significant improvements in your ability to control cookies, EE6.1 pro extends these abilities, so it might be worth updating to EE6.1 or better if that is an option for you. HTH

Comment: You get better responses to your question if you add information about EE version in use and php version in use.